# Smart way to remove PDO statement rows integer keys and relative values

Tags: php, pdo, associative-array

I have a PHP page showing user a query content.

If a *csv* parameter is passed, I let the user download the results in csv like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query_select);
$stmt->execute($params);
if ($format == 'csv'){
  $fobj = fopen('php://output', 'w');
  header('Content-Type: text/csv');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $search_text . '.csv"');
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    if (!$i++) {
      fputcsv($fobj, array_keys($row));
    }
    fputcsv($fobj, array_values($row));
  }
  fclose($fobj);
  exit();
}
```

Problem is `$row` contains data as this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => apple
    [0] => apple
    [colour] => red
    [1] => red
)
```

so my csv file ends up with duplicate data:

```
name,0,colour,1
apple,apple,red,red
```

Which could be a smart way to get instead what user expects?

```
name,colour
apple,red
```

Comment: So use a fetch method with flag to not return numeric indicies? Like [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) with `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as the fetch style.

Comment: I really laugh at those who downvoted, as probably think I should be born knowing about fetch modes different from the default behaviour. :D

Comment: They probably think you should have been able to google this for yourself *shrug*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the fetch mode like below:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use the `PDO:FETCH_ASSOC` for some reason you can use this for your array:

```
array_filter( $array, 'is_string', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY );
```

this will return an array with the keys that are strings only

Comment: this is more of a workaround versus best practice of "using the right setting" with `$stmt`.

Comment: as I said - if he doesn't want for some reason the fetch assoc thingy or the array comes from something else he can use this. I wanted to post it as comment, because it may become in handy, but it doesn't fit as comment imho.

Comment: I agree it is better as an answer than a comment.  I just wouldn't want SO researchers to reach for this method before Dileep's "best practice" method.

Comment: Even tho I accepted the other answer as the right way, I'm happy someone also tells me how to do if, someway out of the pdo context, I want to remove integer keys as in subject. +1